# Firefox ESR loads old certificates after updating from 52 to 60

Tags: firefox, certificate

After Firefox ESR 52 was updated to 60, I've been unable to access my online bank. According to the bank's phone support, I've suddenly started using an old, supposedly still valid but revoked certificate, which was installed some time ago, possibly before I started using ESR.

Basically, my old (by now revoked) certificate is there, but my newer certificate isn't, despite being used normally up to the day before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is likely related to changing from 32 to 64 bit installation or changing to the ESR release (bank requiring a specific signing extension which was not updated), the old certificates are still there.

**Resolution:**

1. In the profile folder (Windows: `%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile_id>.default`), make backups of `cert8.db` and `cert9.db` files.
2. Install the previous, working version of Firefox (in this case 52) and close it.
3. In the profile folder, delete the `cert9.db` file.
4. Restart Firefox, making sure not to update it.
5. Open list of certificates in Firefox. All correct certificates should be listed there.
6. Back up all certificates to a file (and you still have the `cert8.db` and `cert9.db` backups just in case)
7. Delete all certificates
8. Update Firefox
9. Import new certificates from the file